# SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal in Firebug

Tags: javascript, firebug

I'm getting that error when I call this javascript function:

```
function kickUser(id_userChat){
$.post("chatFuncs.php", { action: "kick", id_user: id_userChat });  
}
```

this "kickUser" function is generated for every user connected to my chat box, like this

```
$listUsers .= '<img src="imgUsers/'.$DBClass->nomImg($rowUsers['id_user'],$posImg).'" height="'.$heightImg.'" width="'.$widhImg.'"/>
<span class="styleMsg">'.$rowUser['nameUser'].'</span>&nbsp;
<a href="#" class="BtnKick" onClick="kickUser('.$rowUsers['id_user'].')">Kick</a></br>';
```

and the action "kick" is just an update to my database where I remove the user from my chatUsers table

If I change $rowUsers['id_user'] for $rowUsers['userName'] the error changes to:
**ReferenceError: 'userName' is not defined** (i changed the real name of the user for 'userName' just for this example).

Comment: Why is this tagged java? Do you mean javascript?

Comment: yeah i meant javascript. This is my first time asking

Comment: No Problem mate. Welcome aboard.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Identifiers in JavaScript can't begin with a number; they *must* begin with a letter, `$` or `_`.

---

I'm guessing it's coming from this:

```
onclick="kick_user('.$rowUsers['id_user'].')">Kick</a>
```

If you mean to pass a string, then you need to quote the value being passed.

```
onclick="kick_user(\"'.$rowUsers['id_user'].'\")">Kick</a>
```

I don't know PHP, so maybe you need different escaping, but this should give you the idea.

Comment: this was the solution:
onclick="kickUser(\''.$id_user.'\')">Kick</a></br>';
you were the problem was the escape, do u know where can i learn more about escaping ? ... thanks for your help.

Comment: @user2088447: I don't know PHP, but if you were building the string in JavaScript, you can build a string with nested quotation marks if they are of a different type `"foo 'bar' baz"`, or of the same type if you escape them,  `"foo \"bar\" baz"`. If the `\ ` has special meaning in PHP, then it could be that you'd need `\\ ` instead.

Comment: Nice Answer. Odd thing that quotations work but `String` function does not work!

Answer (score 1):

The resulting JavaScript code will be

```
kickUser(userName)
```

…and obviously there is no js variable `userName`. You want to pass a string instead:

```
kickUser('userName');
```

So add the quotes/apostrophes to the output, and don't forget to escape the `$rowUsers['userName']` properly. It's quite the same for `$rowUsers['id_user']`, which seems to have output even an invalid identifier.

Comment: What did you try? What did it output? What was the error message this time?

Comment: i tried adding quotes to the function like this: kickUser('userName') but everything stopped working so i undo it.