# Issue in parsing a JSON numeric value

Tags: json

I having a JSON value which returns from the server. I can.t Parse this value. Find the below JSON value

```
{"Result":{"d8bf6ab7-21a2-4964-a2cf-e7a1db097f08_FROM":"FROM"}}
```

If i try to get the value like

```
console.log(Result.d8bf6ab7-21a2-4964-a2cf-e7a1db097f08_FROM);
console.log(Result[d8bf6ab7-21a2-4964-a2cf-e7a1db097f08_FROM]);
```

It throws error

```
SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
```

Comment: check following links and see if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392619/syntaxerror-identifier-starts-immediately-after-numeric-literal-passing-php-va and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883397/javascript-firebug-error-identifier-starts-immediately-after-numeric-literal

Comment: @BhavikShah - Already check the above link which you given, i am not understand what's wrong with my json data. It has been quoted properly only right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var obj = {"Result":{"d8bf6ab7-21a2-4964-a2cf-e7a1db097f08_FROM":"FROM"}};

console.log(obj.Result["d8bf6ab7-21a2-4964-a2cf-e7a1db097f08_FROM"]);
```

Comment: It works, can you explain why i cant use . operator to get the value??? like obj.Result.***

Comment: You can't get it because you have hyphens which are considered as minus signs.

Comment: Read this **[Property Name Guidelines](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jsoncstyleguide.xml#Property_Name_Guidelines)** and you will understand. If my answer is correct, then accept it so that it will be useful for others.