# Onclick SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

Tags: javascript, php, onclick, firebug

I have an onclick function:

```
onclick='deleteRow(".$bon['Werkbonnummer'].");updateVak(".$bon['Stellingvak'].");)'`<br/>
<br/>
Implemented in:<br/>
echo "<td><button class='delete' onclick='deleteRow(".$bon['Werkbonnummer'].");updateVak(".$bon['Stellingvak'].");)'>Klaar</button></td></tr>";`<br/>
```

When I push the button, FireBug gives me this error:

```
SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
deleteRow(71);updateVak(4D);)`<br/>
`-----------------------^

<br/><br/>
```

Can somebody point out what I did wrong?

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand? That's invalid syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal in Firebug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966133/syntaxerror-identifier-starts-immediately-after-numeric-literal-in-firebug)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`4D` is not a valid number. If you want it to be handled as a string, you must surround it with quotes (`"4D"`). If you want it to be handled as an hex number, use `0x4D`.