# Pass Server side UserGUID to a Clientside Ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I need to pass User Guid to the Ajax function,But when i tried i'm getting error

> SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

My Serverside Code

```
public Guid GetUserID()
{
    Guid currentUserId = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;

    return currentUserId;
}
```

Part of Client Side Code

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        LoadUserUploadFiles();
    });

    id = "<%=GetUserID()%>";
    function LoadUserUploadFiles(id) {

        alert(id);
        var url = '<%= ResolveUrl("/WebMethods.aspx/GetIndividuallyUploadedFiles") %>';

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: id }),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (Result) {

                var html = '<table class="table-hover">';
                html += '<thead>';
                html += '<th>Username</th>';
                html += '<th>Upload Date</th>';
                html += '<th>Download</th>';
                html += '<th></th>';
                html += '</thead>';
                html += '<tbody>';
                $.each(Result.d, function (key, value) {
                    html += '<tr>';
                    html += '<td>' + value.UserName + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + value.DateStr + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + '<a href="' + value.FilePath + '">Download</a>' + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + '<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteUploadFile(this,' + value.Id + ')" >' + '</td>';
                    html += '</tr>';

                });
                html += '</tbody>';
                html += '</table>';

                $("#uploaddata").html(html);
            },


            error: function (e, x) {
                alert(x.ResponseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal in Firebug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966133/syntaxerror-identifier-starts-immediately-after-numeric-literal-in-firebug)

Comment: You will pass guid to the implementation, not to the function signature itself. In function signature you should have parameter name.

Comment: @afzalulh pls add the answer

Comment: @TechGuy - answer added with example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function signature you should have the parameter name. While calling the function you should pass the guid to the function. See the example below:

**MARKUP:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <script>
        // Notice "id" is the parameter name here
        function LoadUserUploadFiles(id){
            alert(id);

        };
    </script>
        <input id="test" type="button" value="test" onclick='LoadUserUploadFiles("<%=GetUserID()%>")' />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CODE:**

using System;

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public Guid GetUserID()
    {
        Guid currentUserId = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
        return currentUserId;

    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
You can change you code like this:

```
   <script>
        $(function () {
            LoadUserUploadFiles('<%=GetUserID()%>');
            function LoadUserUploadFiles(id) {
                alert(id);
                var url = '<%= ResolveUrl("/WebMethods.aspx/GetIndividuallyUploadedFiles") %>';

                $.ajax({
                //Rest of the code goes here
```

Comment: @in my case how to store a value ? I need When page load it fires

Comment: I'm bit confuzing about your answer :(

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! Edited the code to clarify. How you are calling the `LoadUserUploadFiles` function?

Comment: I cannot get the markup section.System side is OK...Here i edited my question with full Ajax call.. can you pls give a solution to it

Comment: Please see my edit. You can debug the script in Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap quotes around the GetUserId call.

```
function LoadUserUploadFiles("<%=GetUserID()%>")
```

I found this answer by Googling. Always make a search engine your first stop before asking question.