# Javascript: SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

Tags: javascript, escaping, url-encoding

I need to fix that (not mine) code:

```
var addr = escape('<a   href="')%3B%2509%2509addr&#32;+=&#32;escape(utf8_encode('mailto%253A'))%3B%2509%2509addr&#32;+=&#32;encodedEmail%3B%2509%2509addr&#32;+=&#32;escape('.html">');
```

it seems that it worked in older version of javascript, but it's broke now ... encodedEmail var is set, %3B is semicolon, %2509 is %09 = [tabulator]

I got an error at %3B saying SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal.

What is wrong?

After I fix that I will offer free service from that code - a force fighting again spam.
Please help me, thanks in advance, warmly, Gregor

Comment: See that `'` that ends your string? Think that might have something to do with it?

Comment: You've not escaped a `'`, so it's ending your string literal early and causing problems

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal in Firebug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966133/syntaxerror-identifier-starts-immediately-after-numeric-literal-in-firebug)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that would have worked in any version of JavaScript. You have a string ending:

```
var addr = escape('<a   href="')%3B%2509%2509addr&#32;+=&#32;escape(utf8_encode('mailto%253A'))%3B%2509%2509addr&#32;+=&#32;encodedEmail%3B%2509%2509addr&#32;+=&#32;escape('.html">');
// String ends here ----------^
```

...then the `)` closes the parens for `escape`. The `%` that follows will be interpreted as a remainder operator, then the `3B` is a syntax error.

The solution is to put the characters you want in the string, in the string. I can't at the moment guess what those are.